# Post data in asp.net web API with header

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Hi every one I am new to Asp.net Web API and I had my question [post data using asp.net Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676333/post-data-using-asp-net-web-api) and got my answer accepted.

This is an extension to the same question I want to post data with some header value in the Postman and my code is as follows

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostCustomer([FromBody] NewUser userData, string devideId)
{
    //My code 
    return response;
}
```

When I hit this in Postman passing values in JSON format in BODY - raw I got message as follows

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>     No action was found on the controller that matches the request.

Please help me.

Comment: Show your routing configuration and how exactly you send this request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have added some additional `devideId` string parameter to your action. Make sure that you are supplying a value to it as a query string when making the request:

```
POST http://localhost:58626/api/customers?devideId=foo_bar
```

If you don't want to make this parameter required then you should make it optional (in terms of optional method parameter in .NET):

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostCustomer([FromBody] NewUser userData, string devideId = null)
{
    ...
}
```

Now you can POST to `http://localhost:58626/api/customers` without providing a value for this parameter.

Remark: You don't need to decorate a complex object type (such as `NewUser`) with the `[FromBody]` attribute. That's the default behavior in Web API.

---

UPDATE: Here's how you could read a custom header:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostCustomer(NewUser userData)
{
    IEnumerable<string> values;
    if (this.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("X-MyHeader", out values))
    {
        string headerValue = values.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    ...

    return response;
}
```

Comment: instead of passing as parameter how can I read from header and get the header value?

Comment: By using the `Request.Headers` collection in your code and more specifically the `TryGetValues` method on it. I have updated my answer to illustrate it with an example.